# Angular 2 alert on delete action

Tags: angular

What's the right way to implement "Are you sure" alert in Angular 2 before making an important action such as **delete**?

Couldn't find any guidlinese for it or some common module for this.

Hope someone knows about any releated module of built in angular 2 component for it, Thanks..

Comment: There is no right way. Some don't want a confirmation dialog, other ask twice.

Comment: My suggestion is to provide a one action delete button,no confirmation pop-up,but afterwards provide an Undo action button as well.